# Is "not having...full time" partial negation or complete negation?

Tags: meaning, grammar

I got a bit confused by this sentence: "I’ve got used to not having a man around full time." I am not sure if it is partial negation or complete negation. Does this mean:

1. I've got used to occasionally having a man around, or;
2. I've got used to not having a man around at all?

Thanks. Here is the context:

> I’m a bit afraid of us being together all the time; he is full of vigour and I’m a tired middle-aged woman. And besides I’ve got used to not having a man around full time.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with your first interpretation.

> I’m a bit afraid of us being together *all the time*...And besides I’ve got used to not having *a man* around *full time.*

Not being around *full time* doesn't imply not being around *at all*; it simply means not being present *at all times*. Though a man is not always there, a man is there at certain times.  Thus, a man is there occasionally. In this case, the man = he.

Note that if you remove the elements in question, there is a clear implication of absence:

> I'm a bit afraid of us being together. And besides, I've gotten used
>   to not having a man around [at all].

This is not the case, however. The addition of the elements lends credence to the notion that he is neither fully present nor fully absent, but instead occasionally there.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the main meaning that the sentence wants to convey  can be understood from the expression *full time*. She is saying that she is no longer used to having a man always with her and  that  implies that she  may like to  a man for a shorter time.
Form the sentence you attached I understand that the woman in question no longer desires a fully-committed relationship, but probably an occasional one.